# How to model and retrieve data that have a common Table?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

If I have a User table that splits into multiple types of user (via identifying relationship): eg - ClientUser, EmployerUser, EmployeeUser - how would I identify what type of user I have if I'm limited to querying the User table?

The reason is that I don't know the type of user at run time. So let's say I do a query and that result gave me a list of user, how then do I model this, so that I can perform certain action based on the user type?

Is it a good practice to just have a column as "user_type"and store the user type as VARCHAR/TEXT? But then what if a user can be of multiple types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the type informaton you must have a column type in you model .. if you have more then a type related to an user you should use a proper table for one-to-many relationship eg:

```
 table user_type 
 - id,
 - user,
 - type


 id   user    type 
 ---  -----   -----
  1   user1   type1
  2   user1   type2
  3   user2   type3 
  4   user3   type2
```